How do I calculate the value of this limit
How do I calculate the value of this limit
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt n\right).$$
I think the limit is a special case like the one you need to amplify with the conjugate.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Hint: for $k>0$,$$0\le\sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n}\le\frac{k}{\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{k}{2\sqrt{n}}.$$

Hint

Method 1 : $$\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt n=\sqrt n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-2\right).$$ Then, you can use the fact that $$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}+o(x),$$
whenever $x\to 0$.

Method 2 : Using your idea, notice that :
$$\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt n=(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt n)+\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n\right).$$
Then, indeed you can use the conjugate method.

Thank you, now I can easily split into two limits and is way more easier.
